# How we find the contorsion tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, curvature

I know that the formula for contorsion tensor is

$$K^{\mu\nu}_a=\frac12({T_a}^{\mu\nu}+T^{\nu\mu}_a-T^{\mu\nu}_a)$$

I want to know how I can find ${T_a}^{\mu\nu}$.

What kind of contraction do I follow to get this component?

Comment: From [your previous question about torsion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/673714), can we assume you're happy to write $T_\alpha^{\;\;\mu\nu}$ in terms of $T^\rho_{\;\;\kappa\lambda}$?

Comment: I want to know how can I write first component in terms of second or vice versa, or how can I contract second component to get the first one?

Comment: You mean you want the torsion in terms of the contortion? You probably don't want the first term to cancel the third, on the r.h.s.

Comment: I can't cancel first term with the third term as they are not same components

Answer (score 0):

First I think your definition of the contorsion tensor components as it currently stands is flawed or misleading since it amounts to $K^{\ \mu\nu}_a = \frac{1}{2} T^{\ \nu\mu}_{a}$ which most certainly is not correct. A standard definition from literature ([see equation (16) here for example](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0501017)) would be
$$ K^{\ \mu\nu}_a = \frac{1}{2} \left(T^{\ \mu\nu}_{a} + T^{\mu \ \nu}_{\ \ a} + T^{\nu \ \mu}_{\ \ a}\right).$$
If you want to rewrite the torsion in terms of the contorsion you can simply use the antisymmetry of $T_a^{\mu\nu}$ in the upper two indices to infer
\begin{align}
K_a^{\ \mu\nu} - K_a^{\ \nu\mu} = \frac{1}{2} \left(T^{\ \mu\nu}_{a} + T^{\mu \ \nu}_{\ \ a} + T^{\nu \ \mu}_{\ \ a}\right) - \frac{1}{2} \left(T^{\ \nu\mu}_{a} + T^{\nu \ \mu}_{\ \ a} + T^{\mu \ \nu}_{\ \ a}\right) = T^{\ \mu\nu}_{a}.
\end{align}
Note that this amounts $T^{\ \mu\nu}_{a} = K^{\ [\mu\nu]}_a$. However you could also just use the definitions of the torsion, namely
$$ T^\rho_{\ \mu \nu} = \Gamma^\rho_{\ \mu \nu} - \Gamma^\rho_{\ \nu \mu} = \Gamma^\rho_{\ [\mu \nu]}. $$
Where $\Gamma^\rho_{\ \mu \nu}$ are the connection coefficients (which are not the Christoffel Symbols you usually find in GR).